# OpenCart 3.0.3.3 API

Tags: api, opencart3.x

Не нашел нормальную доку на oc api. Кто-нибудь поделится ссылкой?

Что мне нужно сделать? В стороннем файле, в корне сайте, мне нужно получить значение поля email из админки (**config_email**). Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для тех кому интересно будет, помогли мне на форуме oc

```
// Version
define('VERSION', '3.0.3.3');

// Configuration
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.php');

// Startup
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php');

// DB
$db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE, DB_PORT);

$query = $db->query("SELECT `value` FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "setting` WHERE `key` = 'config_email' AND `store_id` = 0 LIMIT 1"); 
if ($query->num_rows) {
  $email = $query->row['value'];
} else {
  $email = 'не найдено';
}

echo 'Email магазина: ' . $email;
```